# How to upload a file in asp.net without reloading a page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, file, upload, reloading

How to upload a file in asp.net without reloading a page

Answer (score 5):

> You will need to perform asynchronous
>   file upload using Ajax and send the
>   file in chunks of bytes.

Authentic AsyncUpload in original **AjaxConotrlToolkit**

**http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx**

Some other references that may interest you..

- **[Matt berseth's Asyncupload](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/07/aspnet_file_upload_with_realti.html)** <-- Recommended
- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)
- [FileUp](http://fileup.softartisans.com/FileUp-244.aspx)
- [Flajaxian FileUploader](http://www.codeplex.com/FlajaxianFileUpload)
- [RadUpload](http://www.componentsource.com/products/telerik-rad-upload/index.html)
- [NeatUpload](http://www.brettle.com/neatupload)
- **[ASP.Net File Upload/Download Module](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/)** <-- Recommended

Answer (score 2):

You should find a suitable ajax uploader. One wise choice would be a jquery ajax uploader. I hope this [jquery ajax uploader](http://www.uploadify.com/), free download, would win your heart. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. but if you need some extended functionality try [this](http://pokein.codeplex.com/releases/view/54534) sample.

Comment: I was just about the share the same link

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html) is a cross-browser script to upload file using ajax. You can search google for Ajax file upload and find out other tools and techniques if this one does not works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-transmit](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-transmit/) is a sophisticated jQuery plugin providing an elegant multi-file upload utility. At the core of the plugin is a small SWF file which provides single or multiple file selection and upload services

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)

it uses jquery to upload multiple files... you can also download sample project which works fine.. and uploads files quickly.
you may need to change your web.config to set lenght of data can be passed ... in the sample project...